# Warning: missing argument error and PHP Warning: curl_getinfo() - Need

Tags: php, web, error-handling, warnings, hosting

**I am getting the following error:**

> *PHP Warning:  Missing argument 5 for VideoConverter::UpdateVideoDownloadProgress() in G:...\VideoConverter.class.php on line 370
>
> PHP Warning:  curl_getinfo() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in G:...\VideoConverter.class.php on line 372*

my php code:

```
private function UpdateVideoDownloadProgress($curlResource, $downloadSize, $downloaded, $uploadSize, $uploaded)
    {
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curlResource, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($httpCode == "200" && $downloadSize > 0)
        {
            $percent = round($downloaded / $downloadSize, 2) * 100;
            if ($percent > $this->_percentVidDownloaded)
            {
                $this->_percentVidDownloaded++;
                $this->OutputDownloadProgress($percent, true);
            }
        }
    }

    // Deprecated - May be removed in future versions!
    private function LegacyUpdateVideoDownloadProgress($downloadSize, $downloaded, $uploadSize, $uploaded)
    {
        $this->UpdateVideoDownloadProgress($this->_curlResource, $downloadSize, $downloaded, $uploadSize, $uploaded);
    }

    private function OutputDownloadProgress($percent, $isRealTime)
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">updateVideoDownloadProgress("'. $percent .'", ' . (($isRealTime) ? 'true' : 'false') . ');</script>';
        $this->FlushBuffer();
    }
```

Comment: The first warning is pretty clear - you're not passing a 5th argument to the function.  Do you need to set a default for the 5th param?  Where do you call this method?

Comment: To append, whatever the first parameter you're passing to that function probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Way more information is needed, also I don't even see the fifth param uploaded even used in the function, why even need it in the first place. also whatever your curlResource is it needs to be the proper object.

Comment: The issue seems to be arising from the way you are _calling_ the function rather than the actual function - please can you supply the code where you're trying to use this function?